# Image Gallery links to medium image instead of FULL size image

Tags: gallery

I am a WordPress veteran and have built some really highly customized sites using WordPress as if it were a framework almost and I love it.  I have not really ever had to use the Gallery feature to much though.

On my current client project I need to utilize the gallery.  I have added a simple plugin to open the gallery thumbnails in a colorbox lightbox instead of having to leave the page everytime you click a gallery image.  That works great except I have one problem.  The image it loads and the image my gallery thumbnails link to is the medium or large image instead of the `FULL` size image.

Below is the Gallery shortcode I am using...

```
[gallery columns="4" ids="124,23,22,18,19,21,20,16,17,15,14,149,150,151,152,153,154"  
     size="thumbnail" link="file"]
```

I had hoped that `link="file"` would link to the full size image but instead it links to this sized image...

`http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/april-bio-300x290.png`

The image that I NEED it to link to is this one...

`http://domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/april-bio`

as you can see it excludes the ending `-300x290.png`

Is there an easy way about doing this?  Or do I need to crreate some sort of filter and manually remove the `-300x290.png` last 12 characters from the URL and then add back on the file extension?

I should mention I am using WooCommerce for the first time on this site, it might affect galleries, I just thought about that.

Any help would greatly be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I just pulled my hair out for a bit over this. I've come to the conclusion that the plugin called "Lightbox Gallery" is to blame. Were you using the same? If so, remove it, and you'll see that your pages link to the full sized images. Try a different lightbox plugin. I've used this plugin on many sites before, but I'm using Version 0.7.4 on this particular one.